# Looping mysql Table Values on a CSS Table

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have a table with date/time, temperature and humidity data stored on a mysql database.

I have a ugly looking but working HTML one so I made a new CSS table using templates and wanted to use the looping in PHP (as in the HTML) to fetch data to the table using the table designers format. (Some datas are manually in as in the sample table photo)

I want to automate that but my PHP script has a problem and does not load the page. shows error.

Im very new to LAMP environment actually and unsure if I can use class variables inside the PHP script without changing anything.

My table looks like this without the python script: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnfcP.jpg

The code is here: https://codeshare.io/amvPYw

(I cannot add code here, it says bad formatting everytime)

Comment: - I suggest replacing the pic with code text (with code markdown), it's much easier for others to work with.

- pls add the full error output, incl. line numbers / stack trace if you can. You can get these from the PHP log on the server.

- just a shot in the dark - you're writing literal double-quotes inside a double-quoted string, e.g `echo "<tr class="row100">";`. Try replacing the external double-quotes with single-quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html element tags are close like `</tr>`. See your end line in while loop.